# VerbNet semantic roles and preposition groups - how to determine matches

Tags: nltk, semantics

Using verbnet to test whether a sentence matches a frame, how does one determine whether the semantic role specified in the verbnet frame is appearing in the sentence or not?

e.g. on [this verbnet class](http://verbs.colorado.edu/verb-index/vn/escape-51.1.php) there is a frame `Theme V {{+path}} Destination`. Is it somewhere specified how is it to be determined for a given sentence, whether it indeed has a `Theme` role or not, whether or not it indeed has a Destination role or not, in the right location? how does one identify a `Destination` v.s. a non-Destination?

And likewise is `path` defined anywhere?

I am not sure I could deduce that in the otherwise definitive description of VerbNet found [here](http://verbs.colorado.edu/verb-index/VerbNet_Guidelines.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The best and most accurate way to deduce this information is by doing it manually. If you want to automate this, what you are looking for is a VerbNet parser. Check the work of Ana-Maria Giuglea and Alessandro Moschitti (university of Rome), who implemented tools that allow for recognizing the VerbNet frames and classes in sentences.